# How to optimize and reduce the time of deserialization in a nested list(3 levels down)?

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, gson, deserialization

I have a very huge json data which I need to deserialize & convert it into a list(collection) to be consumed in a recyclerView later, I use **gson(version 2.8.8)** for the deserialization. The issue is I need to make iteration in 3 loop to get to the final data and add it, as the right type, to the resulted list.

I'm facing a huge **outOfmemory**, a freezing screen and sometimes a crash because of the large amount of the data.
I tried a simple **for, forEach, asSequence()?.iterator()? and even .asSequence()?.asStream()?** but nothing is working.

the code below is in the repository, I call it from a viewModel via **viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)** to be finally observed from the fragment:
**lifecycleScope.launch {
viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) { ...}}**

Here's the code I use:

```
  private fun formatToPost(posts: List<ArticleLivePost?>?): LinkedList<ArticleLiveItem> {

        val items = LinkedList<ArticleLiveItem>()
        val gsonParser = GsonBuilder().create()

        posts?.asSequence()?.iterator()?.forEach { postsList ->

            postsList?.posts()?.asSequence()?.asStream()?.forEach { post ->

                val contentList = JsonParser.parseString(post.content()).asJsonArray

                val contents = mutableListOf<ArticlePostLiveItem>()
                val title = StringBuilder(post.title())

                for (content in contentList) {
                    val type = content.asJsonObject.get(TYPE_KEY).asString
                    Timber.d("listPosts type$type")
                    val element = content.asJsonObject.get(ELEMENT_KEY)
                    Timber.d("listPosts element$element")


                    when (type) {

                        DATEPOST.valueType -> {
                            val postDate = gsonParser.fromJson(
                                element.toString(), DatePost::class.java
                            )
                            contents.add(postDate)
                        }

                        IMAGEPOST.valueType -> {
                            val postImage = gsonParser.fromJson(
                                element.toString(), ImagePost::class.java
                            )
                            contents.add(postImage)
                        }

                        //****** Lot of other types remain to add yet

                    }
                }
                items.add(Post(title, contents))
            }
        }
        return items
    }
```

Comment: I'd look into where your memory is actually being used and looking to reduce that.  Of particular concern to me is the IMAGEPOST data type-  if you're actually loading bitmaps there it won't work at all-  you need to do that lazily when you actually need them, images are memory expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of story:

Origin of the strange behaviour of the recyclerView:
It was placed in a nestedScrollView.
the rapid solution was to put it outside of that nestedScrollView.